# 3d view dicom android

Tags: android, 3d, visualization, dicom

I would like to reconstruct 3d images from a set of dicom images. I hope you are aware of dicom images. I am planning to use OpenGLES for generating 3d view of images. Like I have a set of images as an image stack or image array. I want to generate 3d view of those images in android. The images are the output of ct scan or MRI scan. I am planning to use 2.3 or 3.0 of android. So my first question is, is it possible in android to generate a 3D view from an array of images? Can you give me some hints. I am new to android and OpenGL. Please help.

Comment: This question is unfortunately way too broad to be answered in its current form. The first problem you should tackle, long before GLES or Android become part of the question, is how you want to make a 3D visualization. This is a broad field, but a starting point might be the [marching cubes-algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes).

Comment: Magnus Hoff is right.  In addition to that, and a step back, are you doing volumetric rendering based on your stack of images, or are you doing surface rendering based on some processing of the stack of images?  The former requires greater computation power than the latter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I render DICOM images in 3-D in an Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015539/how-can-i-render-dicom-images-in-3-d-in-an-android-application)

Comment: This is the older question, but I edited the newer one by this same user to be a little clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well. will not be an easy task, but, first of all you have to decide what donyou whant to do,,
3D volumerender needs lot of cpu power, but there are some android devices that can do it, also a lot of memory, and that would be a problem.
surface rendering is far less requiring and you can benefit from ogl. but today medical application is on the 3d volume rendering side...

there are open source libraries like ued on Osirix viewer (mac) and other linux implementations  (ie VTK) ,, you sould go that way...